# Naming the bins of histogram

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

This query is designed to make a histogram with bin sizes of 50.
[image]

So as histograms go this means that there are 1013 objects with a count(*) between 0 and 49.

I would like to make the bin read like

```
0-49           1013
50-99          2147
100-149        1571
```

My attempt isn't quit doing what I need

```
select interval + ' - '+interval*50-1 as bin,count(*) as number from
(

select  count(tblclaims.patientid) as counts, count(tblclaims.patientid)/50 as interval 
from tblclaims
inner join patient on patient.patientid=tblclaims.patientid
and patient.admissiondate = tblclaims.admissiondate
and patient.dischargedate=tblclaims.dischargedate
group by tblclaims.patientid


) as t
group by interval
order by bin
```

I know this is going to have cast the `interval + ' - '` stuff as a varchar, but when I tried that things got way out of whack

Comment: You should replace count(tblclaims.patientid) with just tblclaims.patientid.  Using an aggregation function on a field used by a group by is rather unusual.  This doesn't break the query, but it makes it harder to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if the only problem is casting, You have to cast every number part apart :

```
select cast(interval*50 as nvarchar(max)) + '-' + cast(interval*50+49 as nvarchar(max))
```

Comment: I added the "*50" to the first part of the interval.  The questioner had it incorrect in his original query.

Comment: this doesn't quite get it.  the bins using this method are named `0-1`, `50-49`, etc.

Comment: I had an AHA! moment and I was going to answer it myself, but you beat me to it.  Nice work :)